# Change the background color of Fragment in code

Tags: android, fragment

How to change the background color of a fragment in android programmatically  instead of xml.

Answer (score 4):

Just do in your code:

```
fragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

being `fragment` you `Fragment` object, and the argument the color you want. You can also parse colors using `Color.parseColor(string)` method (e.g `Color.parseColor("#RRGGBB")`).

Comment: In my situation, fragment.getView() == null. I used newInstance method solved the problem.

Comment: Put the answer in onStart(). The view's created by then.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** In your xml of the fragment you want to change its background color, define the layout you're using with an id value such as:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">
```

**Step2:** Make an object of the layout type your're using  and change the background color such as:

```
final ConstraintLayout constraintlayout;
constraintlayout=view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
constraintlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.maroon);
```

**Note1:** it can be any layout, i'm using a `ConstraintLayout` in this example.

**Note2:** `maroon` is a color I defined in `clolrs.xml`, use yoru own or you can import the Color class instead and use it such as `(Color.BLACK)`.